# how to understand the origin in vtkImagedata?

Tags: coordinates, vtk

I don't know how to understand the origin in vtkImageData. The [document](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html#a439eddbb7ba6b456fddbf83635e932ed) says that the origin is the coordinate of (0,0,0) in image. However, I use the vtkImageReslice to get two resliced image, and the origins are different but the images are the same. My code is:

```
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy, numpy_to_vtk 
import vtk 
import numpy as np 

def vtkToNumpy(data): 
    temp = vtk_to_numpy(data.GetPointData().GetScalars()) 
    dims = data.GetDimensions() 
    numpy_data = temp.reshape(dims[2], dims[1], dims[0]) 
    numpy_data = numpy_data.transpose(2,1,0) 
    return numpy_data 

def numpyToVTK(data): 
    flat_data_array = data.transpose(2,1,0).flatten() 
    vtk_data_array = numpy_to_vtk(flat_data_array) 
    vtk_data = numpy_to_vtk(num_array=vtk_data_array, deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT) 
    img = vtk.vtkImageData() 
    img.GetPointData().SetScalars(vtk_data) 
    img.SetDimensions(data.shape) 
    return img 

img = np.zeros(shape=[512,512,120]) 
img[0:300,0:100,:] = 1 

vtkImg = numpyToVTK(img) 

reslice = vtk.vtkImageReslice() 
reslice.SetInputData(vtkImg) 
reslice.SetAutoCropOutput(True) 
reslice.SetOutputDimensionality(2) 
reslice.SetInterpolationModeToCubic() 
reslice.SetSlabNumberOfSlices(1) 
reslice.SetOutputSpacing(1.0,1.0,1.0) 

axialElement = [ 
    1, 0, 0, 256,
    0, 1, 0, 100,
    0, 0, 1, 100, 
    0, 0, 0, 1 
] 
resliceAxes = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4() 
resliceAxes.DeepCopy(axialElement) 
reslice.SetResliceAxes(resliceAxes) 
reslice.Update() 

reslicedImg = reslice.GetOutput()
print('case 1', reslicedImg.GetOrigin())
reslicedNpImg = vtkToNumpy(reslicedImg)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(reslicedNpImg[:,:,0])
plt.show()
```

For another axialElement:

```
axialElement = [ 
    1, 0, 0, 356,
    0, 1, 0, 100,
    0, 0, 1, 100, 
    0, 0, 0, 1 
]
```

The two different axialElement would generate the same image, but the origin of image are different. So, I am confused about the origin in vtkImageData.

Answer (score 0):

When you read in the image - you are using the numpy to vtk functions that read and create a vtkImageData object. Do these functions set the origins to be what you expect?

`img.SetOrigin()` needs to be called and fed the expected origins. Otherwise Origin will be set to a default value (the same for your two images). Printing out the imagedata and seeing if the spacing, origin, direction are what you expect is important.

Comment: The ```vtkImg``` is created by numpy, and the origin should be defualt (0, 0, 0). But, the ```reslicedImg``` is resliced from the ```vtkImg```, I think the origin point should not be (0,0,0). Am I right?